# Convert decimal into days, minutes hours and seconds in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

How can I convert a decimal into days, hours, minutes and seconds?

The decimal will show the number of minutes, and I'd like to convert it into either a string which says "`X days, Y hours, Z minutes and W seconds`", or to show "`DD:HH:MM:SS`"

I have found a few posts similar, but none which are done in R.

So far, my code is:

```
seconds=55800
lengths=strftime(as.POSIXct(seconds, origin = Sys.Date(), tz = "UTZ"), format = "%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I need a new origin however. Since 55800 seconds is 15.5 hours, and the result shows 19 days 15 hrs 30 mins since the origin is based on today's date (19th). I need to create a universal origin somehow.

Comment: Please show an example and expected output

Comment: Is it so complex to do a few divisions  and multiplications ?

Comment: I've added my code, and I know what the issue is, just not how to solve it. I didn't include it previously since i'm convinced a more eloquent way is possible. @Tensibai - No it is not, who said that it was?

Comment: Use UNIX epoch as your origin, `origin="1970-01-01"`

Comment: @sym246 as far as you don't show any attempt, it seems you didn't even try by yourself before asking... Now it's better and TomNash gave you the correct answer, use proper origin (that said with strftime, you'll have a problem above 31 days).

Comment: The result comes in at 1d 16:30 - This is still incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says the input is the number of minutes but the code starts out with seconds.   I have assumed minutes.

**1)** Calculate the number of days and then convert the minutes to POSIXct and produce the string using `sprintf`.  No packages are used.

```
# input
mins <- 55800 / 60

days <- mins %/% (24 * 60)
ct <- as.POSIXct(60 * mins, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC") # POSIXct
sprintf("%02d:%s", days, substring(ct, 12))

## [1] "00:15:30:00"
```

**2)** Using chron and `days` from above it is slightly shorter and avoids potential time zone errors:

```
library(chron)
sprintf("%02d:%s", days, times(chron(mins / (24 * 60))))
## [1] "00:15:30:00"
```

**Update:** Fixed/simplified.  Added (2).

Comment: I see where my minutes/seconds is confusing in the original post - it doesn't really matter which i use. However, 5000 minutes is equal to 3 days 11 hours 20 mins - Not 3 days 6 hours 20 mins... (or 55800 is not 10 hours 30 in the newest edit)

Comment: Have fixed.  55800 seconds is 930 minutes which is 15.5 hours.

Comment: Have simplified slightly.

Answer (score 4):

The `lubridate` package has a variety of helpers that are handy for similar use cases.

```
> require(lubridate)
> seconds_to_period(55800)
[1] "15H 30M 0S"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Original minutes vector
minutes <- 14.64416

# Get the number of whole minutes, save in `mins`
mins <- floor(minutes)

# Get the decimal from `minutes` and multiple by 60 to get
# the number of seconds within a the minute. Save in `secs`
secs <- round(minutes %% mins * 60, 0)

# Paste them together in whatever format you would like
paste0(mins, ":", secs)
```

```
[1] "14:39"
```